# What is an easy way to transfer my development directory to a new computer

Tags: xcode

I copied my development directory to Google Drive. When I try to open a project from the new computer XCode gives me a "cannot be opened because it is missing its project.pbxproj file" error. I have checked the answers on stackoverflow for similar questions but they don't seem to apply to my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't just use a version-control system and host it on GitHub or BitBucket? You could just push the projects to github, then clone them on the new machine.

Comment: No good reason. I can try it and see if it is easier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be in your xxx.xcodeproj bundle. Did you copy that? Is it there on "Google Drive"? What happens if you do "Show Package Contents" in the finder with your .xcodeproj file?

Comment: project.pbxproj does exist in xxx.xcodeproj along with project.xcworkspace and a directory 'xcuserdata' both in the original xxx.xcodeproj  as well as in the GoogleDrive version.